# How to refer selected date in Controller action method using MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have used two text boxes for start date and end date and I want to check some conditions based on  selected start date and end date. How to refer selected start date and end date in controller function.

I just need to store selected start date and end date to string variable to check some conditions.

View:

```
@Html.Label("StartDate", "Start Date:") 

 @Html.TextBox("startdate", String.Empty, new {id="datepicker"}) 
 @Html.Label("End date", "End Date:")</td>
 @Html.TextBox("enddate", String.Empty, new { id="datepicker1" })

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function (event) {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$(function (event) {
$("#datepicker1").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: put textboxes inside a form and post to an action in controller

Comment: Why would you store dates as `string` and not `DateTime`?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried like String a =startdate.ToString(). The thing is i don't know how to refer startdate. Can you please tell me syntax?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Along with date, i need to check some conditions for string varialbe also. The combination of  date and string will be first row of table as per my requirement

Comment: Both the controls you have shown are dates (i.e. they should be typeof `DateTime`). What is the `string` your referring to? And you would make all this a lot easier if you create a simple view model and bind to your model and post it back.

Comment: You can also post the start date and end date as JSON using $.post to controller method and refer them.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: I want to know how to convert date to string and hence i have not posted the complete code

Comment: @Girish Sakhare : Thank you for your suggestion. Let me try and update to you

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to help. What are you posting back to. If the method is `public ActionResult Something(string startDate, ..)` then its already a string. If its `public ActionResult Something(DateTime startDate, ..)` then `string myDate = startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` or whatever format you want.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Yes. Got the point. Thank you. I am trying to do the following task. For the selected date and particular group, shift has to be allocated to the employees. Then shift lead needs to be allocated for each shift.